# Buying stock/ETF and nationality?

Tags: stocks, etf, international-trading, mexico

I recently tried to setup a Finanzen.net account to start playing with a trading app here in Germany, however only a specific list of nationalities are allowed to do this. Is there a way to buy stock/ETF in Germany being a citizen from Mexico?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a *International Trading Brokerage Account* that's based out of Mexico. I'm not familiar with Finanzen, but it looks like it's Germany based.

International trading brokerage accounts allow you to make Stock/ETF trades in other countries, but not all international brokerage accounts allow trading in all countries. You can usually look on the broker's website for their list of supported markets. For example, [this link](https://www.fidelity.com/stock-trading/international-stock-trading) shows what international markets Fidelity supports. You may also need additional approval to make international trades. Again using Fidelity as an example, after opening a brokerage account an additional step must be taken to get approval to trade internationally.

What I would do if I was you...

1. Find a brokerage account in your country of residence
2. Make sure it supports international trading
3. Make sure it supports international trading in Germany